# Вывести значения из нескольких таблиц MySql

Tags: mysql, join

Всё просто, но не могу довести до ума:
- Есть, скажем, две таблицы: cities (id/city/country_index) & countries (id/country)
- Нужно вывести на экран результат Стран Город.

При таком и других джойнах он выводит только то, что стоит возле СЕЛЕКТ, как вывести две и более колонки(Страна/Город/Улица...)?
SELECT country FROM countries JOIN cities ON country.id = cities.country_index ;

Comment: дак напишите _возле селект_, то что хотите вывести?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял так:
после SELECT, перед FROM перечисляешь поля которые хочешь вывести

```
SELECT country, city FROM countries JOIN cities ON countries.id = cities.country_index
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё ОК.